# Date embedded in json string

Tags: javascript, json

I've a function, that receives a String and convert It to a json Object.

The problem is, that sometimes, te function could recibe a Date, and I need it to be a date! (Not a string).

For example, the string that I send to the function is like this:

```
[{
        "date" : new Date(2013 - 01 - 01),
        "Weigth" : "120.00"
    }, {
        "date" : new Date(2013 - 01 - 01),
        "Weigth" : "110.00"
    }
]
```

In other cases, the string will look like this:

```
[{
        "age" : 12,
        "Weigth" : "120.00"
    }, {
        "age" : 15,
        "Weigth" : "110.00"
    }
]
```

But, in the first example, the parser throws an error.
How can I detect this case, and force the parcer to generate an javascript object with this atributes?

Thanks!

Comment: How does `new Date(2013-01-01)` happen to be part of the string? How ist this invalid JSOn generated?

Comment: You can't, because that would not be JSON. If the client cooperates by evaluating the response as JS code instead then it would be possible (but it would also make the client vulnerable to attacks from the server).

Comment: In JSON dates are formated like `"{"d":"2013-11-25T14:41:24.726Z"}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to `eval()` your string but I would suggest you to generate a correct `JSON` instead because `eval()` may lead to the problems that doesn't worth the profit of this easy conversion:

```
var invJSIN = '[{"date":new Date(2013-01-01),"Weigth":"120.00"},{"date":new Date(2013-01-01),"Weigth":"110.00"}]'
var something = eval(invJSON)
```