# Date embeded string to json object

Tags: java

I'm getting following string when requested for json object.

```
{
    "singular": "Financial Report",
    "plural": "Financial Reports",
    "statusId": "A",
    "records": [
        {
            "id": 131114,
            "companyId": 645588,
            "userId": 5520,
            "title": "Annual Report",
            "typeId": "AR",
            "statusId": "A",
            "periodDate": new Date(1409457600000),
            "isImmediate": true,
            "createdDate": new Date(1419276796000),
            "lastModifiedDate": new Date(1419276796000),
            "releaseDate": new Date(1419276796000),
            "releaseDateTimeFormatted": "Dec 22, 2014 02:33 PM",
            "releaseDateFormatted": "Dec 22, 2014",
            "canDistribute": true,
            "wasDistributed": false,
            "companyName": "Sunridge Gold Corp.",
            "typeName": "Annual Report",
            "name": "Annual Report - Annual Report",
            "statusDescript": "Active",
            "userName": "Doris Meyer",
            "symbol": "SGCNF",
            "primarySymbol": "SGCNF",
            "primaryExchange": "OTC Link",
            "isCaveatEmptor": false,
            "edgarSECFiling": false
        }
    ],
    "sortOn": "releaseDate",
    "sortDir": "DESC",
    "totalRecords": 76165,
    "pages": 3047,
    "currentPage": 4,
    "pageSize": 25
}
```

I was trying to parse it using google gson library it throwing com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException

Is there any way to avoid new Date in json string above.

Comment: similar question but in javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195685/date-embedded-in-json-string/27654865#27654865

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Gson gson = new Gson();
MyObject myObj = gson.fromJson(jsonString,MyObject.class);

I tried checking Whether the above json string is valid json or not using http://jsonlint.com/ it's throwing error as not valid json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not JSON.  Rather it is Javascript which includes calls to a Javascript (I think) method called `newDate`.

> Is there any way to avoid new Date in json string above.

It depends on what is generating the not-JSON string!  If you can fix that, you are good to go.  Otherwise, I don't imagine that any JSON parser is going to cope with it.

---

For the record, the syntax for JSON is defined on the http://json.org site.  If someone argues that the stuff you have shown us is real JSON, point them at the syntax ... and at the ECMA standard that that page cites as the authoritative source.

Comment: So ... tell "otcmarkets" that their JSON is invalid.

Comment: Its external market, we don't have any control over their data.

Comment: You are a customer.  You can tell them they are wrong.  You can point out to them that you are going to have to write a custom parser to deal with their "not-JSON" nonsense, and that you are NOT HAPPY.

Comment: I know that above string is not a valid json, i was asking for help to format that to json.

Comment: I suppose you could do a string replace using a regex.   (Read the javadocs for the `Pattern` class!!!) But no JSON parser is going to do that for you.

Comment: thank you, I decided to use regex as you suggested.